# max value of a dataframe column so far

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi have have the following dataframe (df)

```
       temp
0      10
1      23
2      12
5      24
```

And I trying to achieve:

```
       temp     max_so_far
0      10      10
1      23      23
2      12      23
5      24      24
```

I was trying to use:

```
df['max_so_far'] = df.temp.rolling(window= df.index).max
df['max_so_far'] = df.temp.rolling(window= df.index.astype(int)).max
```

however I always get the error that window must me an integer. any suggestion how to go around this

thanks

Comment: df.index gives you a range of indexes. Not a single value. Rolling expects its window to be an constant integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`pd.Series.cummax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cummax.html) instead of the rolling window:

```
print(df.temp.cummax())
0    10
1    23
2    23
5    24
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as `2`, and then add `fillna`:

```
df['max_so_far'] = df.temp.rolling(window= 2).max().fillna(df.temp[0])
```

Addition to Jan's answer, to assign:

```
df['max_so_far']=df.temp.cummax()
```

Both cases:

```
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   temp  max_so_far
0    10        10.0
1    23        23.0
2    12        23.0
5    24        24.0
```